# Laravel 5.3 URL query string

Tags: php, laravel, url, laravel-5.3

I have a URL like this:

```
www.test.com?query[ch_id]=1,query[category_id]=2,query[item_id]=3
```

Using Laravel functions what is the tidiest way I can retrieve as:

```
$query = [
 'ch_id' => 1,
 'category_id' => 2,
 'item_id' => 3,
];
```

Comment: check in create parameter Request $request for your method and then check for dd($request->all());

Comment: Sorry - what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this is method you are calling with query parameters.

```
public function yourmethod(Request $request){
   dd($request->all());
}
```

**EDIT**

As per your requirement.

```
$str = "www.test.com?query[ch_id]=1,query[category_id]=2,query[item_id]=3";
$arr = parse_url(str_replace(",","&",$str));
parse_str($arr['query'], $query);
print_r($query);
```

**Output**

```
Array ( [query] => Array ( [ch_id] => 1 [category_id] => 2 [item_id] => 3 ) )
```

[parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) - Parse a URL and return its components
[parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) - Parses the string into variables

Comment: Not what I'm looking for 
[ "ch_id" => "1,query[category_id]=2,query[item_id]=3" ]

Answer (score 0):

use laravel request helper : `$query = request('yourArrName')`
or after inject the `Illuminate\Http\Request` in your method of Controller,
use the `$query = $request->yourArrName`

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for it produces:
array:1 [
  "ch_id" => "1,query[category_id]=2,query[item_id]=3"
]

Comment: sorry, not see the `,` . I think you use the `&`.